# What is the shortest game that has never been played?

Tags: opening, database

In the publicly available databases (at all levels of play, including Lichess), what is the shortest unique sequence of moves from the opening which has never occurred? (That is, if it were played, it would be a novelty.)

Are there, for instance, any 2 move sequences?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a unique 4 ply solution. 1. Na3 a6 2. g4 h5 hasn't every been played by anyone as far as I can tell... yet.

Obviously as soon as someone answers this question, I could play a friend on lichess and "knock out" any answer. So the question really only makes sense when you discuss serious games between masters. In which case, already 1. Na3 a6 is a novelty in "professional" play.

Comment: Consider the question as being restricted to games that existed before the question was asked.

Comment: `1. Na3 f6 2. h3 b5` seems to be another.

Comment: And quite a few possibilities `1. d3 Nh6 2. Bd2 ??`

Comment: Alekhine 2 Qg4/Qh5, or Scandinavian 2 Bc4/Qg4 ? . . .  (Or even 2 Ba6; likewise Caro-Kann 2 Bb5 and various sequences where White's second move hangs wB on a6 or h6)

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few 4 ply lines that have 0 games on Lichess.

- `1. Na3 f6 2. h3 b5`
- `1. Nh6 2. Bd2 ..`
- `1. f3 h6 2. Na3 f5`

Comment: Oh, hmm. I just realised I'm reading the stats wrong. The opening database Lichess gives are based on positions, not games, so they include transpositions. There are potentially more games that haven't been played, even if the positions they would reach have.